# for-Loop in screen does not work

Tags: bash, for-loop

I would like to use screen to stay attached to a loop command on a ssh session, which is most likely going to run for a couple of hours. I am using screen because I fear that my terminal will get disconnected while the command is still running. This is the loop-command:

```
for i in *; do echo $i/share/sessions/*; done
```

(`echo` will be replaced by `rm -rf`).

I have tried multiple variants of `screen 'command ; command ; command'`, but never got it working. How can I fix this? Alternatively, could you suggest a workaround for my problem?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with steps someone can follow to reproduce (1) the correct behavior *outside* screen, and then (2) the failed behavior *inside* screen?

Comment: It's not clear how you are invoking, or failing to invoke, `screen` here. A simpler solution is to just run the job in the background with `nohup`, and output results to a file.

Comment: As an aside, the loop isn't useful; `echo */share/sessions/*` and similarly for `rm`

Comment: @tripleee, I suspect that by converting the code from a one-liner you may have obfuscated the issue -- my interpretation is that the OP is passing the `for` loop as an *argument* to `screen`.

Comment: Hmm, you could be right - I'll revert that change

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to run:

```
screen 'for i in *; do echo $i/share/sessions/* ; done'
```

This results in a `Cannot exec [your-command-here]: No such file or directory` because screen doesn't implicitly start a shell; rather, it calls an `execv`-family syscall to directly invoke the program named in its argument. There is no program named `for i in *; do echo $i/share/sessions/*; done`, and no shell running which might interpret that as a script, so this fails.

You can, however, **explicitly** start a shell:

```
screen bash -c 'for i in *; do echo $i/share/sessions/* ; done'
```

---

By the way -- running one copy of `rm` per file you want to delete is going to be quite inefficient. Consider using `xargs` to spawn the smallest possible number of instances:

```
# avoid needing to quote and escape the code to run by encapsulating it in a function
screenfunc() { printf '%s\0' */share/sessions/* | xargs -0 rm -rf; }
export -f screenfunc       # ...and exporting that function so subprocesses can access it.
screen bash -c screenfunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Screen for long running commands can be used like this :

```
$screen -S session_name
//Inside screen session 
$ <run long running command>
$ //press key combination - Ctrl + a + d - to       come out of screen session 
// Outside screen session
// Attach to previously created session
$screen -x session_name
```

For more details look at man page of screen.
Another application which works similar way and is very popular is [tmux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need really for `screen` here.

```
nohup rm -vrf */share/sessions/* >rm.out 2>&1 &
```

will run the command in the background, with output to `rm.out`. I added the `-v` option so you can see in more detail what it's doing by examining the `tail` of the output file. Note that the file won't be updated completely in real time due to buffering.

Another complication is that the invoking shell will do a significant amount of work with the wildcard when it sets up this job. You can delegate that to a subshell, too:

```
nohup sh -c 'rm -rvf */share/sessions/*' >rm.out 2>&1 &
```